# AutoMapper core Condition not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I want the null value during mapping DTO to DBO model to be ignored. This is the code:

DTO / DBO models have both property named items:

```
public virtual ICollection<price_list_item> items       { get; set; }
```

DBO constructor:

```
public price_list()
{
    this.items = new List<price_list_item>();
}
```

DTO constructor has no propert initialization

```
public price_list()
{        
}
```

AutoMapper Profile:

```
 this.CreateMap<DTO.price_list, DBO.price_list>()
        .ForMember(m => m.id, src => src.Ignore())
        .ForMember(m => m.currency_id, src => src.MapFrom(f => f.currency))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.items, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.items != null)))
```

API Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
        [Route("{id:long}")]
        public async Task<DTO.price_list> UpdateOneAsync(long id, [FromBody]DTO.price_list payload)
        {
            if (payload == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("payload");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(payload.items == null);

            var _entity = await this.IDataRepository.price_lists
                                            .Where(w => w.id == id)
                                                .Include(i => i.items)
                                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (_entity == null)
            {
                NotFound();
                return null;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(_entity.items.Count);

            // map fields to existing model
            this.IMapper.Map<DTO.price_list, DBO.price_list>(payload, _entity);

            Console.WriteLine(_entity.items.Count);
```

When I send to API a JSON without any sign of 'items' property, Console output is:

```
True
1200 // price list in dbo has 1200 items
0    // here I need to have still 1200 items
```

What am I doing wrong? Why the condition is not respected and items property is not 'skiped' ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection).

Comment: Try a PreCondition instead.

Answer (score 1):

Lucian thanks, **PreCondition** solved the problem. This is working code:

```
this.CreateMap<DTO.price_list, DBO.price_list>()
        .ForMember(m => m.id, src => src.Ignore())
        .ForMember(m => m.currency_id, src => src.MapFrom(f => f.currency))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.items, opt => opt.PreCondition(src => (src.items != null)))
```